# django - Accessible url pattern only for certain group of users

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-users

Is there a way to limit access to url pattern only for certain group of django users?
for example, everything that starts with `/settings/` shuld be accessible only for the administration group.

or maybe it is possible to create a new decorator such as `@group("administration")` and add it to each view that is limited to the group?

personally I prefer the second way, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

django provides a [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) decorator to do exactly this.  You can pass it any function and if the function returns a false value, the view is not shown.

The example explains it better:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def email_check(user):
    return '@example.com' in user.email

@user_passes_test(email_check)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

In your case, you want to see if the user is in a particular group:

```
def in_admin_group(user):
   return 'administration' in user.groups
```

Comment: In addition, this is compatible with `@login_required`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to either

- add a specific permission to the group and use permission_required: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator

or

- test that the user is in the group with user_passes_test: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test